# MySQL, coalesce equivalent for empty values?

Tags: sql, mysql

I know that coalesce will return the first non-null value that is passed to it. is there something simlilar that will return the first not empty / not false value?

example:

```
select FunctionIWant(0,'','banana') as fruit;  //returns banana.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the ANSI [CASE statement/expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN LENGTH(col) = 0 OR col IS NULL THEN 'banana'
         ELSE col
       END AS fruit
```

There's no boolean in SQL, or MySQL.  MySQL actually stores the value as an INT, values zero or one:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN col = 0 THEN 'banana'
         ELSE col
       END AS fruit
```

Answer (score 243):

You could make NULL from empty string in MySQL:

```
SELECT coalesce(NULLIF(email, ''), 'user@domain.example') FROM users WHERE id=1000000;
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, much easier then other solutions, and still allows me to use `COALESCE`!

Comment: lovely. was looking for a solution that works in H2, this one does as well!

Comment: works great for an ORM like Idiorm Paris that allows expressions to be used

Comment: A very useful method. I used it here:  insert into ... on duplicate key update email= coalesce( NULLIF(email, ''), values(email) ) and now if there's a value in the DB it stays, and if there isn't one there, the new one gets loaded.

Comment: Amazing, i used this for custom "priority" sorting in combination with FIND_IN_SET() => ORDER BY  COALESCE(NULLIF(FIND_IN_SET(id,'12,45,11'), 0), 999999999) ASC, name ASC

Comment: I can't get this to work in the latest versions of MySQL, checked in Mysql 5.6

Comment: Fantastic when used with `CONCAT_WS` too, which will ignore null values.

Comment: This also works great for ORDER BY FIELD(mycolumn, 'A', 'B', 'C') where you want the values which don't match to appear last instead of first.  So ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(FIELD(mycolumn, 'A', 'B', 'C'),0),999999999).  I've been looking for an elegant way to do this for a long time, and here it is.  Answer is years old, but I never saw it before...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `COALESCE(NULLIF(col, ''), ...)` is less verbose than a `CASE` expression.

Comment: This also works wonderful when creating virtual colulmns.  For instance, "completed int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(NULLIF(response->>'$.completed',''),0)) STORED"

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in MySQL, but you can develop your own stored function. The main difficulty here is that the number of parameters to pass to the function can vary.

One possible solution could be to pass a string with a set of values separated by a separator by using the `CONCAT_WS` function (see [CONCAT_WS() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)). You would also have to define a string delimiter in case your separator would be included in one of the values of the set.

Here is an example script:

```
DELIMITER |;
CREATE FUNCTION MY_COALESCE (
     p_set_string TEXT
    ,p_delimiter CHAR(1)
  ) RETURNS TEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(REPLACE(
                      CONCAT(p_delimiter,p_set_string,p_delimiter)
                     ,CONCAT(p_delimiter,'0',p_delimiter),'')
                 ,CONCAT(p_delimiter,p_delimiter),'')
             ,p_delimiter,2),p_delimiter,-1)
    ;
END;
|;
DELIMITER ;

SET @separator=',', @delimiter='$';
SELECT
  MY_COALESCE(
      CONCAT_WS(CONCAT(@delimiter,@separator,@delimiter),0,'','banana')
     ,@delimiter
    ) as fruit
;
```

When running the previous script you get the following output:

```
MySQL> --------------
MySQL> SET @separator=',', @delimiter='$'
MySQL> --------------
MySQL> 
MySQL> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MySQL> 
MySQL> --------------
MySQL> SELECT
MySQL>   MY_COALESCE(
MySQL>       CONCAT_WS(CONCAT(@delimiter,@separator,@delimiter),0,'','banana')
MySQL>      ,@delimiter
MySQL>     ) as fruit
MySQL> --------------
MySQL> 
MySQL> +--------+
MySQL> | fruit  |
MySQL> +--------+
MySQL> | banana |
MySQL> +--------+
MySQL> 1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

You can of course adapt the value of the string delimiter so there won't be any conflicts with your set values.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT IF(myValue > 0, myValue, 'empty string') AS Value FROM myTable;
```