# Django order items by two fields, but ignoring them if they're zero

Tags: django, sql-order-by, django-orm

I have the following model (greatly simplified for the purposes of this question):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2)
```

For the majority of products, price will be filled but sale_price will not be. So, I can order products by price like so:

```
Product.objects.order_by('price')
Product.objects.order_by('-price')
```

However, some products will have a sale_price, and I can't find a way to order these neatly so that the sale price interleaves with the normal price. If I try ordering by both fields:

```
Product.objects.order_by('sale_price','price')
```

...then all the products that aren't on sale appear together, followed by all that are, instead of interleaving the prices.

Does this make sense? Does anyone have a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the extra() QuerySet method to create an extra field in your query using the COALESCE function in SQL, which returns the first non-NULL value it's passed.

```
Product.objects.extra(select={"current_price":"COALESCE(sale_price, price)"}, order_by=["-current_price"])
```

You have to put your order_by in the extra() call as the extra manual field "doesn't really exist" as far as the rest of the ORM is concerned, but the syntax is the same as normal Django order_by()s.

See the extra() documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Shame I have to use extra, but if the ORM can't handle it then there's no other choice! Thanks.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use extra() when you have to, doing this kind of thing at the database level is much faster and probably clearer than doing it via a hack in your Python code.

The only point to keep in mind is to stick to standard SQL. e.g., use COALESCE which is in ANSI SQL rather than for example NVL which is an Oracle extension. As long as you do that, extra() is perfectly portable. Problems like yours, with portability concerns, is why extra() was added as an alternative to raw SQL.

Comment: it change the type of `sales_price` and `price` from decimal field to string/unicode.
like the `current_price` would be a unicode string now, rather than a decimal field. how to handle that?

Comment: what is the alternative of this approch of COALESCE?

Answer (score 21):

If you stumble upon this requirement and happen to be using **Django 1.8** and higher, you can use [`django.db.models.functions.Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) for a slightly nicer, cross db-engine, solution:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Product.objects.annotate(
    current_price=Coalesce('sale_price', 'price')
).order_by('-current_price')
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use this ordering as the default ordering on the model?

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to work well with Charfields. I have two charfields 'name' and 'nickname'. Nickname is often empty. If I do: .annotate(current_name=Coalesce('name', 'nickname')).order_by('current_name'). 

The ordering seems to look fine, but if you have names of different length (a.k. 'test' and 'testj') with the same nickname ('testnickname'), and some other object with just 'test' and no nickname, it would display as: 'testnickname', 'test', 'test', 'testnickname' (my __str__ methods check if testnickname, then show that, otherwise just name).

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I don't have null fields, but I have '' fields instead (as recommended per Django documentation). Then the Coalesce doesn't work well.

Comment: Django ORM would simply execute COALESCE on the db, so the behavior you see is most likely the correct behavior of the function on your DB. For example on a solution consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519604/484127).